# What corelation test to perform for two rasters?

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have two raster files, one containing the dNBR (burn severity), the other one NDVI change (regeneration after forest fire). I am trying to see if the two are correlated, i.e. if there is an enhanced change in NDVI value in areas with a higher dNBR value (higher burn severity).

The two raster have the same extent. I have loaded the rasters as data frames into R with their respective x and y coordinates and merged the two, resulting in one data frame containing the location of each pixel with its NDVI and dNBR value.

**This is the head of the data:**

```
          x       y dNBR_subset_sites NDVIdiff_subset_sites
120 1436935 6807858        0.02246130           -0.03928924
121 1436935 6807868        0.02477366           -0.03689700
414 1436945 6807838        0.01721925           -0.04642320
415 1436945 6807848        0.01618838           -0.05474144
416 1436945 6807858        0.02184808           -0.04721129
417 1436945 6807868        0.02267021           -0.04459375
```

**This is my code:**

```
NDVIdiff_ss_s <- raster(paste0(wd, "path/to/NDVIdiff_subset_sites.tif"))
dNBR_ss_s <- raster(paste0(wd, "path/to/dNBR_subset_sites.tif"))

dat_NDVIdiff_ss_s<-as.data.frame(NDVIdiff_ss_s, xy = TRUE)
dat_dNBR_ss_s<-as.data.frame(dNBR_ss_s, xy = TRUE)

merged_ss_s <- merge(dat_dNBR_ss_s, dat_NDVIdiff_ss_s)
merged_ss_s <- na.omit(merged_ss_s)

ggplot(data = merged_ss_s, aes(x = dNBR_subset_sites, y = NDVIdiff_subset_sites, color = dNBR_subset_sites)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "red")

cor_merged_ss_spearman <- cor.test(merged_ss_s$NDVIdiff_subset_sites, merged_ss_s$dNBR_subset_sites, method = "spearman")
print(cor_merged_ss_spearman)

cor_merged_ss_kendall <- cor.test(merged_ss_s$NDVIdiff_subset_sites, merged_ss_s$dNBR_subset_sites, method = "kendall")
print(cor_merged_ss_kendall)

cor_merged_ss_pearson <- cor.test(merged_ss_s$NDVIdiff_subset_sites, merged_ss_s$dNBR_subset_sites, method = "pearson")
print(cor_merged_ss_pearson)
```

This is the plotted data:
[image]

**These are the results of the tests:**

```
Warning message:
In cor.test.default(merged_ss_s$NDVIdiff_subset_sites, merged_ss_s$dNBR_subset_sites,  :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
> print(cor_merged_ss_spearman)

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  merged_ss_s$NDVIdiff_subset_sites and merged_ss_s$dNBR_subset_sites
S = 6.3524e+10, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
     rho 
0.810412 


    Kendall's rank correlation tau

data:  merged_ss_s$NDVIdiff_subset_sites and merged_ss_s$dNBR_subset_sites
z = 103.48, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      tau 
0.6141549 


    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  merged_ss_s$NDVIdiff_subset_sites and merged_ss_s$dNBR_subset_sites
t = 158.68, df = 12619, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.8102741 0.8219253
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.8161826
```

**My question** is if this is a valid approach of testing the correlation of the two rasters and what method is the right one to choose.